# Magento 1.9 pagination url issue

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I have change the pagination URL from `p` to `page` like below:

```
magento/test.html?page=1
```

But when I click on any pagination, product page shows same product on every page.

If I change from `page` to `p` in URL then it works. 
I need to know how do I change `p` to `page` in model. 
Currently I have overridden the `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Pager` class.

Comment: Did you reindex?

Comment: Could you please share override class code ?

Answer (score 0):

I override pager class , this code :

```
public function getPageVarName()
{
    return "page";
}
```

this replaces the "p" to "page" in url but while clicking on pagination 1,2,3 same product is seen untill I put "p" on url. I think in model its getting "p" from url we need to replace to "page" in model also.
But can you tell me in which model the "p" parameter is passed ?